# Grunt Uglify cannot access code within a closure

Tags: gruntjs, uglifyjs

**Edit: this issue actually seems to be specific to uglifyjs itself. Running the code in an online tool like http://lisperator.net/uglifyjs/ gives the same results**

I've got a grunt task that simply concatenates some files and then uses uglify to minify the resulting file.

file a:

```
console.log('this is file a');
```

file b:

```
(function () {
    console.log('this is file b');
});
```

The concat works fine and I get concatenated file in my dist directory (testout.js) that looks like this:

```
(function () {
    console.log('this is file b');
});
console.log('this is file a');
```

The the uglify task runs and produces testdist.min.js. Which looks like this:

```
console.log("this is file a");
```

None of the code from file b is included! As soon as I remove the closure from file b the second console.log is included in uglify's output.

Here's the entire grunt file.

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),



    concat: {

        test: {
             src: [
                'src/filea.js',
                'src/fileb.js'
            ],
            dest: 'dist/testout.js'

        },

    },

    uglify: {
        thing: {
            files: {
              'dist/testdist.min.js' : ['dist/testout.js'] 
            }
       }

    },


    watch: {

        js: {
            files: ['src/*.js'],
            tasks: ['concat','uglify']
        }
    }
});


grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');

grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch']);

}
```

Comment: EDIT: This seems to work if I turn the function expression in to an Immediately invoked function expression but I'm still not sure hat I had before doesn't work.

    (function () {
        console.log('this is file b');
    })();